# Using Momentary SPST with KL25 Microcontroller

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am currently working on a project to develop a binary calculator using a KL25 micro-controller. The idea is to use a couple of momentary SPST switches to control which pins are enabled and to move left and right through that array. The issue that I am having is that when the code gets to the loop for controlling the calculator it will just move to the end of the function. Any insight is appreciated.

```
#include <MKL25Z4.h>                    // Device header
#include <stdio.h>
#include <system_MKL25Z4.h>             // Keil::Device:Startup

typedef uint8_t boolean;
static int place = 0;

#define MASK(x)  (1UL << (x))

// First set of Switches is the 5 Directional
#define SW_UP_POS (63)  //Addition   on Port C
#define SW_DN_POS (64)  //Subtraction    on Port C
#define SW_LT_POS (65)  //Division   on Port C
#define SW_RT_POS (66)  //Multiplication     on Port C
#define SW_LEFT (67)        //Left Move  on Port C
#define SW_RIGHT (68)   //Right Move     on Port C
#define SW_ENABLE (73)  //Toggle LED logic  on Port D
#define SW_RESET (74)       //Reset Calculator  on Port D

//LEDs positions
#define LED_1_1  (1)            // on Port E
#define LED_1_2  (13)           // on Port E
#define LED_1_4  (14)           // on Port E
#define LED_1_8  (15)           // on Port E
#define LED_1_16 (21)           // on Port E
#define LED_1_32 (22)           // on Port E
#define LED_1_64 (23)           // on Port E
#define LED_2_1  (27)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_2  (28)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_4  (30)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_8  (31)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_16 (32)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_32 (33)           // on Port A
#define LED_2_64 (44)           // on Port B
#define LED_3_1  (45)           // on Port B 
#define LED_3_2  (46)           // on Port B
#define LED_3_4  (55)           // on Port C
#define LED_3_8  (56)           // on Port C
#define LED_3_16 (57)           // on Port C
#define LED_3_32 (58)           // on Port C
#define LED_3_64 (61)       // on Port C
#define LED_OVERFLOW (62)   // on Port C

    void init_5way_switch(void);    //added prototype to clear the warning
    void init_5way_switch(void){
    
    // Select GPIO and enable pull-up resistors for pins connected to switches 

        PORTC->PCR[6] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1) | PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 63
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<6);
        PORTC->PCR[7] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 64
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<7);
        PORTC->PCR[8] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 65
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<8);
        PORTC->PCR[9] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 66
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<9);
}
    
    void init_otherSwitches(void);  //added prototype to clear the warning
    void init_otherSwitches(void){
        
        PORTC->PCR[10] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 67
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<10);
        PORTC->PCR[11] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 68
        PTC->PDDR=(0<<11);
        PORTD->PCR[0] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 73
        PTD->PDDR=(0<<0);
        PORTD->PCR[1] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 74
        PTD->PDDR=(0<<1);
    }
    
    void init_led(void);    //added protoype to clear the warning
    void init_led(void){
     // Set ports to outputs
            
    PORTE->PCR[0] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1) | PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 1 as GPIO
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<0);             //pin 1 is input
    PORTE->PCR[20] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 13
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<20);
    PORTE->PCR[21] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 14
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<21);
    PORTE->PCR[22] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 15
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<22);
    PORTE->PCR[29] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 21
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<29);
    PORTE->PCR[30] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 22
    PTE->PDDR=(1<<30);
//  PORTE->PCR[31] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 23
//  PTE->PDDR=(1<<31);
    PORTA->PCR[1] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 27
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<1);
    PORTA->PCR[2] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 28
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<2);
    PORTA->PCR[4] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 30
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<4);
    PORTA->PCR[5] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 31
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<5);
    PORTA->PCR[12] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 32
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<12);
    PORTA->PCR[13] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK; //pin 33
    PTA->PDDR=(1<<13);
    PORTB->PCR[1] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 44
    PTB->PDDR=(1<<1);
    PORTB->PCR[2] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 45
    PTB->PDDR=(1<<2);
    PORTB->PCR[3] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 46
    PTB->PDDR=(1<<3);
    PORTC->PCR[0] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 55
    PTC->PDDR=(1<<0);
//  PORTC->PCR[1] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 56
//  PTC->PDDR=(1<<1);
    PORTC->PCR[2] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 57
    PTC->PDDR=(1<<2);
    PORTC->PCR[3] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 58
    PTC->PDDR=(1<<3);
    PORTC->PCR[4] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 61
    PTC->PDDR=(1<<4);
    PORTC->PCR[5] |= PORT_PCR_MUX(1)| PORT_PCR_PS_MASK | PORT_PCR_PE_MASK;  //pin 62
    PTC->PDDR=(1<<5);
        
}

void calculator(void);
void calculator(void){
        
                unsigned int first = 0;
                unsigned int second = 0;
                unsigned int solution = 0;
            
            unsigned int firstRow[7]={LED_1_1,LED_1_2,LED_1_4,LED_1_8,LED_1_16,LED_1_32,LED_1_64};  //first row array
          unsigned int secondRow[7]={LED_2_1,LED_2_2,LED_2_4,LED_2_8,LED_2_16,LED_2_32,LED_2_64};   //second row array
            unsigned int thirdRow[7]={LED_3_1,LED_3_2,LED_3_4,LED_3_8,LED_3_16,LED_3_32,LED_3_64};  //third row array
            

            
            while(PTC->PDIR==(0 << 8) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 9) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 7) ||  PTC->PDIR==(0 << 6)){               
    
                    
            while(PTD->PDIR==(0 << 1)){
            while(PTC->PDIR==(0 << 8) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 9) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 7) ||  PTC->PDIR==(0 << 6)){
        if (PTC->PDIR==(0 << 10)){
                place++; // will toggel the led slector left by incramenting the array by 1
                        if (place < 0){ //these keep the user from taking the led selector our of bounds
                    place = 0 ;
                }
                if (place > 6){
                    place = 6;
                }           
            }
            if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 11)){
                place--; // will move selector to right by decrementing the array by 1
                            if (place < 0){ //these keep the user from taking the led selector our of bounds
                    place = 0 ;
                }
                if (place > 6){
                    place = 6;
                }           
        //      GPIO_PCOR(SW_RIGHT);
            }
            if (PTD->PDIR==(1 << 0)){               
                    PTE->PTOR =firstRow[place];
            }
        }
            }
            place = 0;                                                                      //will move the array selector back to position 0
            while(!(SW_RESET)){
            while(PTC->PDIR==(0 << 8) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 9) || PTC->PDIR==(0 << 7) ||  PTC->PDIR==(0 << 6)){               
                if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 10)){
                place++; // will toggel the led slector left by incramenting the array by 1
                                if (place < 0){ //these keep the user from taking the led selector our of bounds
                    place = 0 ;
                }
                if (place > 6){
                    place = 6;
                }           
            }
            if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 11)){
                place--; // will move selector to right by decrementing the array by 1
                            if (place < 0){ //these keep the user from taking the led selector our of bounds
                    place = 0 ;
                }
                if (place > 6){
                    place = 6;
                }           
            }
            if (PTD->PDIR==(1 << 0)){               
                    PTE->PTOR = secondRow[place];               }
                    }
                }

            while (PTD->PDIR==(0 << 1)){
                    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<7; i++){
                        if(firstRow[i] == 1){
                            first += 2^i;
                        }
                    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
                        if(secondRow[j] == 1){
                            second += 2^j;
                        }           
                    }           
            }                   
            if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 8)){
                solution = first / second;              
            }
            else if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 6)){
                solution = first + second;
            }
            else if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 9)){
                solution = first * second;
            }       
            else if (PTC->PDIR==(1 << 7)){
                solution = first-second;
            }
            //else if stops from multiple solution request
            if(solution>127){
                PTD->PSOR = (LED_OVERFLOW);             
            }               
            else{                                   //this causes the solution to output only if the overflow is not triggered
            for(unsigned int i=7; i >0; i--){
                if(solution%(2^i)){
                thirdRow[i] = 1;
                solution -= 2^i;
                        }
                for(int sPlace = 0; sPlace < 3; sPlace++){
                    if(sPlace == 0 || sPlace == 1){
                        PTB->PSOR = MASK(thirdRow[sPlace]);
                    }else{
                      PTC->PSOR = MASK(thirdRow[sPlace]);
                            }                   
                        }
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
    }       

    int main(){
        
        SIM->SCGC5 |=  SIM_SCGC5_PORTA_MASK; /* enable clock for port A */
        SIM->SCGC5 |=  SIM_SCGC5_PORTB_MASK; /* enable clock for port B */
        SIM->SCGC5 |=  SIM_SCGC5_PORTC_MASK; /* enable clock for port C */
        SIM->SCGC5 |=  SIM_SCGC5_PORTD_MASK; /* enable clock for port D */
        SIM->SCGC5 |=  SIM_SCGC5_PORTE_MASK; /* enable clock for port E */      
        
        init_5way_switch();
        init_otherSwitches();
        init_led();
        
        int i =1;
        while(i == 1){
        calculator();
        }   
    }
```

Comment: `(0 << 10) == (0 << 8) == (0 << 9) == (0 << 7) == (0 << 6) == (0 << 1) == 0`, so many of your loops are run if and only if `PTC->PDIR == 0`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: What value is e.g. `0<<10`?

Comment: Your code is just too long/complicated to read. Are you debouncing the button inputs?